# Keyboard simulation using a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to create a type writter effect into a textarea, trying to pass keyboard events to it have no effect, from within the context script, this is the code i'm using.

```
function handleResponse(response) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea-chat');
    var event = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {key: 'A', code: 66});
    textarea.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Am I missing permissions? Doing it wrong?

Your assistance is appreciated!

Edit: I need actuall keyboard events, some pages are monitoring those so just updating the value of the textarea is not enough.

Comment: You are assigning wrong value to `code`, I think you meant `charCode: 66`

Comment: Can you also show your listener? I have tried your code and it works

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk which listener?

Comment: the one that should react to this event

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk that listenr resides in some component in the current page (im running as a chrome extension), if I create my own listener on that DOM element, it gets invoked. but that textarea element does not get a new character inputted to it... thats the goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simulate input, you will need to use the debugging api and protocol.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Input

```
chrome.debugger.attach(target, "1.2", function() {
 chrome.debugger.sendCommand(target, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", arguments)
})
```

Comment: How to target an element in a page using this method, I want to target an input field in a page

Comment: @durairajaa you would probably want to use a DOM selector and then apply focus() to it. Then with the focus on the input field the text should populate there.

Comment: target isn't defined correctly in any of the docs, anyone have a better definition?

Comment: actually: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/#type-Debuggee