# How do you mimic key strokes in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I want to be able to mimic the events of a user typing on a keyboard within a Google Chrome Extension in much the same way that one can do it with puppeteer such that it generally fires all the same events as would a user typing manually.

Are there methods available in Google Chrome libraries to facilitate this? I have tried using JavaScript and DOM manipulations client side  directly including firing off events for mouse clicks etc... This works on some pages in lieu of manual events but on a few pages that are crafty only manual and puppeteer library keyboard/mouse events accurately mimic and fire off all events.

If there is a library that facilitates this for Google Chrome Extensions I’d really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Extensions can use the same underlying commands: it's [Input](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/) sent via `chrome.debugger` API, look for examples.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. With this info I was able to find this page which I think gets me pretty close to what I need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619522/keyboard-simulation-using-a-chrome-extension