# Javascript - simulate user input in

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, automation

I'm creating a local chrome extension to automate some work that my team and I regularly do.

We need to fill some input fields in a webpage in a way that **simulates real user interaction/input**; so all events bound to an input field are triggered.

For example, we have an input field that triggers filtering of a list. We want the list to be filtered when the user input is simulated.

The desired outcome we're looking at is similar to Puppeteer's `page.keyboard.type`.

*Note*: just changing the `input.val` via code won't do, as the event triggering the filtering could be bound to the `keydown`, `keyup`, `focusout` or any other event.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

Comment: Also [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849) and [Keyboard simulation using a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634681).